# Java, detect whether a String beyond Long type value boundary

Tags: java, long-integer

Given following `Java` codes:

```
String columnValue = "188237574385834583453453635";
columnValue =(Long.parseLong(columnValue)>Long.MAX_VALUE?"0":columnValue);
```

It throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException` since the input value is beyond `Long`'s maximum value. However, it there an easy way to detect whether a number in a 'string' type get out of `Long`'s maximum value with out using `try` `catch` solution?

Comment: No `long` value can be greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, by definition.

Comment: Extract the source code of `parseLong` and instead of throwing an exception, return a `boolean`. Though, throwing the exception here makes sense, in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lazy way can be to use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("188237574385834583453453635");
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);

System.out.println("a > Long.MAX_VALUE is : " + (a.compareTo(b) > 0 ? "true" : "false"));
```

If performance is important, you will have to test more solutions.

@SotiriosDelimanolis idea is also a good one :

> Extract the source code of parseLong and instead of throwing an
>   exception, return a boolean.

Also there are many `throw` in the code, some are for the format, other are for the overflow, you will have to choose the right ones.

Comment: I really don't understad why this was downvoted, when it is the only good answer.

Answer (score 0):

A really cheesy way:

```
columnValue.length() > ("" + Long.MAX_VALUE).length()
```

Of course this does NOT cover values greater than Long.MAX_VALUE but the same number of digits, only values with more digits.

Comment: Fortunately, 'Long.MAX_VALUE' is 9.22e18, which means that you will only have 7.7% of false positive result **on correctly formed string**. The good point is that you can't have false negative. So it can make a good pre-filter for parsing.

Answer (score -1):

**Not really.**

The only naive partial solution is to compare the length of the String, but that would not work always.

Comment: Fortunately, 'Long.MAX_VALUE' is 9.22e18, which means that you will only have 7.7% of false positive result **on correctly formed string**. The good point is that you can't have false negative. So it can make a good pre-filter for parsing.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a utility method that wraps the try/catch and returns a boolean, something like:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class TestClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(TestClass.isLongString("188237574385834583453453635"));
    }

    public static boolean isLongString(final String longNumber)
    {
        boolean isLong = false;
        try
        {
            Long.parseLong(longNumber);
            isLong = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // do nothing - return default false
        }

        return isLong;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted - it would be nice if you explained why you chose to do that.

Comment: Probably because the exception is still thrown and the OP doesn't want that.

Comment: It is not thrown - it is handled by the method itself, returning a boolean.

Comment: It is thrown and ignored.

Comment: @OferLando, The problem here is that you will not know if a `false` result is caused by an overflow or a malformed string.

Comment: True, but that wasn't the request - if you want to consider malformed string and other possible issues - it should be handled before trying to convert the string into a long.

Comment: I find it regrettable that the `parseLong` function did not gives more informations when it throws exceptions (I looked to JDK 8u31 sources). In C# for example you get an OverflowException or a FormatException depending on the cause of the exception.